# How can a larger mixed model converge while its nested version cannot?

Tags: r, mixed-model, fitting, likelihood-ratio, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset with three fixed effects and two random effects as subjects and items. I'm fitting linear mixed-effect models and comparing models with the log-likelihood ratio to find the best fit.

The largest model that could converge with random slopes is this:

```
m1 = lmer(RT ~ PHON*FRQ*SEM + (1+PHON+FRQ+SEM|Subject) + (1+FRQ+SEM|Item), data = FACTOR, REML=F)

summary(m1)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood t-tests use Satterthwaite approximations
  to degrees of freedom [lmerMod]
Formula: RT ~ PHON * FRQ * SEM + (1 + PHON + FRQ + SEM | Subject) + (1 +  
    FRQ + SEM | Item)
   Data: FACTOR

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 37414.1  37557.0 -18682.1  37364.1     2219 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.7432 -0.4675 -0.2140  0.1257 12.6226 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 Item     (Intercept)  11404.6 106.79                    
          FRQ          15525.9 124.60    0.78            
          SEM          13120.9 114.55    0.14 -0.52      
 Subject  (Intercept) 191857.4 438.02                    
          PHON           661.9  25.73   -0.46            
          FRQ           2380.5  48.79    0.99 -0.33      
          SEM           8397.6  91.64   -0.12 -0.83 -0.26
 Residual             906279.4 951.99                    
Number of obs: 2244, groups:  Item, 180; Subject, 48

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   2026.20      67.03   48.80  30.229   <2e-16 ***
PHON           -63.35      21.65  470.70  -2.926   0.0036 ** 
FRQ             41.67      26.25  210.50   1.587   0.1139    
SEM            -50.96      26.39   55.20  -1.931   0.0586 .  
PHON:FRQ        19.45      22.20 2028.30   0.876   0.3811    
PHON:SEM        10.03      22.36 1944.10   0.449   0.6538    
FRQ:SEM         21.06      22.14 2021.80   0.951   0.3415    
PHON:FRQ:SEM    20.66      20.75 2023.90   0.995   0.3197    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) PHON   FRQ    SEM    PHON:FRQ PHON:S FRQ:SE
PHON        -0.077                                            
FRQ          0.285 -0.033                                     
SEM         -0.055 -0.077 -0.152                              
PHON:FRQ    -0.009  0.079  0.115 -0.056                       
PHON:SEM     0.001 -0.166 -0.041  0.048 -0.028                
FRQ:SEM     -0.006 -0.101  0.399 -0.098  0.109    0.130       
PHON:FRQ:SE -0.029  0.090  0.080  0.083  0.317   -0.192 -0.002
```

And from this model, I started reducing the model dropping one line at a time without touching the random slopes. So I dropped `PHON:FRQ:SEM` by fitting the model below as the next step:

```
m2 = lmer(RT ~ PHON*FRQ + FRQ*SEM + PHON*SEM + 
          (1+PHON+FRQ+SEM|Subject) + (1+FRQ+SEM|Item), data = FACTOR, REML=F)
```

To my understanding, this is the nested (so, smaller) version of the maximum model I fitted first. So if the first model converges, this one should too. But it didn't and I got the following error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

How is this possible? And what should I do?

Comment: +1. I don't know, but what happens if you specify a different solver, such as `control=lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa")`?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number of iterations (e.g. `control=lmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=50000)`) and/or trying different optimizer?

Comment: Thank you very much @amoeba and Matteo Lisi for your comments. As you suggested, I tried using different optimisers and also, increasing the number of iterations. Unfortunately, these approaches did not work, either. I guess I need to find another solution. (Also, thank you amoeba for your note on the model structure.)

Comment: If these are continuous variables try centering and scaling them can improve convergence issues

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example? This seems quite interesting but without something to try myself it is a bit moot. The ` degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues` seems to suggest some collinearity between the predictors. This might be related as to why the larger model fails while the smaller one is fine.

Comment: You could plot the results based on various optimizers. If the results are consistent across optimizers, they would be more trustworthy. A function and a code-through is available at: https://pablobernabeu.github.io/2021/a-new-function-to-plot-convergence-diagnostics-from-lme4-allfit/